# Can you identify this seemingly British uniform in a presumably French portrait?

Tags: france, identification, uniform

The uniform in this presumably French portrait. The portrait was handed down through unknown generations within the de Boissoudy family in the South of France.

Latest family members are perplexed as to why their ancestor is in a "British" uniform. I am speculating that he is not in a British uniform.

[image: Presumably French portrait]

**Can anyone identify the uniform in this portrait?**

Comment: Can you give us any more information on this portrait? Anything you can provide may help save users a lot of wasted research.

Comment: Welcome to History, Isa! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: Portrait was handed down unknown generations within the deBoissoudy family in the South of France. Latest family members are perplexed as to why their ancestor is in a "British" uniform. I am speculating that he is not in a British uniform.

Comment: A closeup of any available details for the buttons or the epaulettes might help. Either a "definitely painted before" or "definitely painted after" date would also assist.

Comment: @Isa the neck looks definately french,but austrian offier necks are similar at that time, and the single buttoned pattern also has french 1790-1800 likeness, but it's quite unclear. do you have a closeup of the buttons?

Comment: my bet would be late 1790 early 1800 sous liutenant ( 1 epaulette) during the egypt campaing, where french demi-brigade officers switched to red and other bright colors for a brief period of time from their usual dark blue. but the neck falls off for that definition, they're not that complex in the pictures you can find  around the net . so i'm not really sure.

Comment: Could be anything. Gendarmes wore red too as did coast watch and various mercenary groups. When was the portrait painted? The artist's name should at least be known.

Answer (score 2):

From the English Wikipedia on [**Red Coat** (military uniform)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_coat_(military_uniform)) regarding **France**:

> The *Irish Brigade* of the French Army (1690-1792) wore red coats supposedly to show their origins and continued loyalty to the cause of Jacobitism. Red coats were also worn by the *Swiss Guard and other Swiss mercenary regiments in the French Army* from the mid-17th to early 19th centuries.

Answer (score 0):

> **Can anyone identify the uniform in this portrait?**

Not easily, there isn't enough detail.

According to [Wiklipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_coat_(military_uniform)):

> The entire Danish Army wore red coats up to 1848 and particular units in the German, French, Austro-Hungarian, Russian, Bulgarian and Romanian armies retained red uniforms until 1914 or later. Amongst other diverse examples, Spanish hussars, Japanese Navy and United States Marine Corps bandsmen, and Serbian generals had red tunics as part of their gala or court dress during this period. In 1827 United States Artillery company musicians were wearing red coats as a reversal of their branch facing colour.[47] However the extensive use of this colour by British, Indian and other Imperial soldiers over a period of nearly three hundred years made red uniform a veritable icon of the British Empire.

You might ask on Bruce Bassett-Powell's [Uniformology](http://www.uniformology.com/)

Comment: Not to mention Napoleon's famous "Red Lancers" of the Imperial Guard.